# How to prevent the changing of integer onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am having an issue with my Ajax. At the moment, I have 5 pairs of elements: the dropdowns (the `span` tags) and the contents of the dropdowns (the `ul` tags). On the `span` tags is an event-listener, for an `onclick`, where if clicked the `drop-downs` appear, and when clicked elsewhere, drop-downs disappear. With hardcoded `li`'s the dropdowns work fine. However, I am trying to populate the `<ul>`s with dynamically generated `<li>`s using ajax. However, the Ajax is misbehaving.

On the `span` I also have another event-listener for `onchange` which calls the js function `calloptions();`, which is my Ajax. What I am trying to achieve is, if you select an option, the options in the other drop-downs change based on what you have selected. What i have the function do is `onchange`, loop from dropdown 0 to dropdown 5 changing the `<li>`'s based on what the values of the all the selects are.

When I debug, however, my value `[k]` changes to `5` by the time `readyState` gets to `[4]` in the first loop? I'm not sure whether the increase in the value of `[k]` on loop 1 is as a result of the `onreadystatechange` or something else entirely that I'm missing. This, therefore, results in the function being unable to overwrite the `<ul>`values because it is looking for `span[5]` while there are only 5 of them, which then prints `Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined (...)`

HTML

```
    <div id="filters">
        <div class="i_drop col column-2">
            <span class="i_drop_select"></span>
            <img class="i_drop_select_function drop" src="./assets/drop_input.png">
            <ul class="i_drop_content"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="i_drop col column-2">
            <span class="i_drop_select"></span>
            <img class="i_drop_select_function drop" src="./assets/drop_input.png">
            <ul class="i_drop_content"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="i_drop col column-2">
            <span class="i_drop_select"></span>
            <img class="i_drop_select_function drop" src="./assets/drop_input.png">
            <ul class="i_drop_content"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="i_drop col column-2">
            <span class="i_drop_select"></span>
            <img class="i_drop_select_function drop" src="./assets/drop_input.png">
            <ul class="i_drop_content"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="i_drop col column-2">
            <span class="i_drop_select"></span>
            <img class="i_drop_select_function drop" src="./assets/drop_input.png">
            <ul class="i_drop_content"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

AJAX

```
function calloptions() { 
var toselect = ["class", "topic", "subtopic", "year", "marks"];
for (var k = 0; k < toselect.length; k++) {

    var filters = document.getElementById("filters"); 
    var span = filters.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var execute = "select";
    var myclass= span[0].innerHTML;
    var topic =span[1].innerHTML;
    var subtopic = span[2].innerHTML;
    var year = span[3].innerHTML;
    var marks =span[4].innerHTML;

    makeRequest('test.php', toselect[k],  myclass, topic, subtopic, year, marks, execute); 

    function makeRequest(url, select, myclass, topic, subtopic, year, marks, execute) {

    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
            alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
            return false;
    }

    httpRequest.open('POST', url);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    httpRequest.send("function="+ execute+ "&toselect="+ select+ "&class=" + encodeURIComponent(myclass) + "&topic=" + encodeURIComponent(topic) + "&subtopic=" + encodeURIComponent(subtopic) + "&year=" + encodeURIComponent(year) + "&marks=" + encodeURIComponent(marks));
    }

    function alertContents() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var response = this.responseText;
            var container = span[k].parentElement || span[k].parentNode ;
            var ul =container.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
            ul.innerHTML = response;
        }
    }
}
}
```

PHP

```
if(!empty($_POST['function']) && !empty($_POST['toselect']))
{
    $toselect = $_POST['toselect'];
    $_POST['function']($toselect);

}

function select($toselect) {
    global $link;

    $variables = "";

    $select_options = array("class", "topic", "subtopic", "year", "marks");     

    $unset_options= array(); $set_options= array(); $set_values= array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($select_options) ; $i++) { 
        if(isset($_POST[$select_options[$i]]) && $_POST[$select_options[$i]] != ''){
            array_push($set_options, $select_options[$i]);
        } else {
            array_push($unset_options, $select_options[$i]);
        }
    }

    for ($i=0; $i < count($set_options) ; $i++) { 
        array_push($set_values, $_POST{$set_options[$i]});
    }

    for ($i=0; $i < count($unset_options); $i++) { 
        $key = array_search ( $unset_options ,  $select_options);

        unset($select_options[$key]);
    }

    $select_options = array_values($select_options);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($set_options) ; $i++) { 
        if ($i<1) {
            $variables .= " $set_options[$i]='$set_values[$i]'";
        } else {
            $variables .= " AND $set_options[$i]='$set_values[$i]'";
        }
    }

    if ($variables != "") {
        $variables = "WHERE" . $variables;
    }

    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT $toselect FROM `questions` $variables";

    $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $test_array = array();

    $i = 0;

    while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $test_array[$i] = "<li>$row[0]</li>";
        $i++;
    }

    $test_array = implode("", $test_array);

    echo $test_array;       
}
```

I printed the parameters being submitted to the PHP file at `httpRequest.send()` and ran them as a `$_GET` in the file, and it works, so I know it not a problem with the PHP, but rather a failure on my Ajax.

I would appreciate assistance with any simpler algorithm/method to achieve the intended goal, but would appreciate even more, help with eliminating my current errors. I am new to both Ajax and javascript and would, therefore, also greatly appreciate a bit of dumbing down. Thanks!

Comment: Make the asynchronous parameter to `false` in the `.open()` method, like this: `httpRequest.open('POST', url, false);`. If you're making the asynchronous parameter to false, don't write any onreadystatechange function, just put the code after `.send()`.

Comment: I haven't tested you idea to its full extent, but from what I have implemented, I get an error saying `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.` While it may work, its deprecated. I'd like to figure out a valid way accomplish this for future knowledge's sake...Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, I still haven't found out what causes my "over-increasing" `[k]` values, but from experimentation, separating the for loop and the Ajax works. Like so:

```
function externalFunction() {

    var toselect = ["class", "topic", "subtopic", "year", "marks"];
    for (var i = 0; i < toselect.length; i++) {
        calloptions(i, toselect[i]);
    }
}


function calloptions(x, toselect) { 

    var form = document.getElementById("filters"); 
    var span = form.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var execute = "select";
    var myclass= span[0].innerHTML;
    var topic =span[1].innerHTML;
    var subtopic = span[2].innerHTML;
    var year = span[3].innerHTML;
    var marks =span[4].innerHTML;

    makeRequest('test.php', toselect,  myclass, topic, subtopic, year, marks, execute); 

    function makeRequest(url, toselect, myclass, topic, subtopic, year, marks, execute) {

        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if (!httpRequest) {
            alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
            return false;
        }

        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
        httpRequest.open('POST', url);
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        httpRequest.send("function="+ execute+ "&toselect="+ toselect+ "&class=" + encodeURIComponent(myclass) + "&topic=" + encodeURIComponent(topic) + "&subtopic=" + encodeURIComponent(subtopic) + "&year=" + encodeURIComponent(year) + "&marks=" + encodeURIComponent(marks));
}

    function alertContents() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var response = this.responseText;
            var container = span[x].parentElement || span[x].parentNode ;
            var ul =container.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
            ul.innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

The search still isn't over though, still trying to figure it out...

Comment: pls see my answer

Answer (score 0):

That increment in the value of `k` isn't due to some mysterious ajax/scope issue it is in fact due to the `for` loop. **k gets incremented even when 
your condition fails** Yes! you heard it right and i admit this really weird .When you loop is over `k` is already equal to 5 note that atm. no response has arrived yet.Since all your callback are in the same function they all refer to same `k` which have value 5 that's why you see the error

```
for (var k = 0; k < toselect.length; k++) {
//....
//
}

console.log(k); //5
```

What can you do?
Well you can simple use `k-1` in your callback functions or just use some other variable increment it yourself but that would only remove this error and still would be buggy because when response comes they all will see k as having same value and update same `<span>`.To solve async. issues we generally use closures try searching on that if you have any doubt you can ask me.