# Strange behaviour of for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Can anyone tell me why `for` loop increments even on failed iteration?

```
for (var n = 0; n <3; n++) {
     alert(n);                  // displays 0 , 1 , 2 
}
alert(n); // gives 3
```

But shouldn't it be like

```
if(condition):
    //desired stuff
    increment;
else:
    exit;
```

I seldom use iteration variable mostly I just throw them away upon loop completion but in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201273/how-to-prevent-the-changing-of-integer-onreadystatechange/41220620#41220620) found it to be the cause of a bug

Comment: How else would you expect the conditional check to fail if `n` *hadn't* been incremented to 3? Its value isn't going to revert back to 2 just because it no longer meets the loop's criteria.

Comment: It's because every variable in javascript belong to the function's scope. This means n still exists after the function.

Comment: Actually, in your example, it should alert '2', or i am missing something?

Comment: Opps it was `n <3;` :p

Comment: @JonK  woudn't `2<2` fail?

Comment: Are we even trying to solve something here still?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Conceptually `n++` is called just after the final statement of the loop body, and the stopping condition is evaluated just before the first statement of the loop body.

So your code is equivalent to

```
for (var n = 0; n < 3; ) {
     alert(n);
     n++;
}
```

Viewed this way, the reason why `n` is 3 once the loop exists ought to be obvious.

Note that in javascript, `n` *leaks* out of the `for` loop.

Comment: But n++ wont run if n == 2.  It only runs up to n == 1 (ie: n < 2).

Comment: @sg-Oops. Typo: the `for` loop is the same as the way the OP has it, aside from my moving `n++`.

Comment: Gotcha!  it would always inc. because otherwise equality cases wont work right

Comment: Absolutely. `n` will always be in the first failed condition when the loop exits.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var n = 0; n <3; n++) {
    alert(n);                 
}
alert(n);
```

Working of for loop is as follows -

1. First it initialize the n to 0;
2. Then it checks the condition whether it is true or not in this case condition is n<3.

   3. Finally it increments the n and again check the condition and if it is true,It again goes in for block. And if the condition is false, It exit the for loop.

**In your code when n=3 condition get false. So final value of n is 3.**

Answer (score 0):

Just executed the code at chrome console:

[image]

It works as expected.

Comment: @Bathsheba: The behaviour you mentioned in your answer wasn't supposed to happen if the loop condition was "<= 2"  or " < 3"?

Answer (score 0):

As you have commented that **n** will be alert with **3**, it is wrong, because when **n** will be **2**, condition will be checked i.e. **2<2** will be wrong, then it will be jump from the loop and will alert **2** not **3**.

Comment: That's right but when it exits the loop k will be 3 cause loop will increment it anyway